# I am unable to login as an organization in django views

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have requirement to build a crm . In that i have 3 things 1 is super user who is there by default.

Second organization in which I use a foreign key of user because I don't want to create a custom user and re write a lot of things third agent who is user as foreign key and connected to an organization no I want to login as organization in the dashboard if I am using the super user as login credential it is telling me required organization instance if I am login using organization account it is giving error NoReverseMatch at /leads/login_handle

Here is my views.py

login and sign up handle code

```
def signup_handle(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        pass1 = request.POST.get('pass')
        pass2 = request.POST.get('re_pass')
        pass2 = request.POST.get('re_pass')
        check = request.POST.get('agree-term')

        if(pass1 != pass2):
            return HttpResponse("Babe your passwod does not matches please try again")
        else:
            x = User.objects.create(email = email,username = email,first_name = name,is_staff = False)
            # x = User.objects.create(name,email,pass1)
            x.set_password(pass1)
            x.save()
            y = Organization(user = x,name = name)
            y.save()
        # print(f"lets verify the data name = {name},{check}")
        return HttpResponse("Babe you have successfully created your account")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("Babe something goes wrong")

def login_handle(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('your_name')
        password = request.POST.get('your_pass')
        # username = email
        # print(f"{username} and password is {password}")
        user = authenticate(request,username=username,password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Babe try again you are not authenticated")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("babe only post method applicable")
```

here is my complete models.py file

```
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
# Create your models here.

class Source(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Followup(models.Model):
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True)
    body = RichTextField(blank = True,null = True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.PROTECT,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Agent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.PROTECT,blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="Agents/images",blank = True)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization,on_delete=models.PROTECT,blank=True,default="")
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name



class Lead(models.Model):
    status = (
        ("fresh","Fresh"),
        ("open","Open"),
        ("closed","Closed"),
        ("pending","Pending"),
    )
    closed_by = (
        ("low_budget","Low Budget"),
        ("we_cant_do","We Cant Do"),
        ("client","Client Converted"),
    )

    pending_by = ( 
        ("with_customer","With Customer"),
        ("with_process","With Process"),
        ("pending_on_us","Pending On Us"),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30,default="")
    assign_to = models.CharField(max_length=30,default="")
    mobile_no = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    message = models.TextField(blank=True)
    source = models.CharField(max_length=30,default="")
    # source = models.ForeignKey(Source,blank=True,on_delete=models.PROTECT,null=True)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    state = models.CharField(choices=status,max_length=20,blank=True,default="fresh")
    closed_by = models.CharField(max_length=15,choices=closed_by,blank=True)
    pending_by = models.CharField(max_length=15,choices=pending_by,blank=True)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to="lead/images",blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

[image]

As the first answer says i added a path in redirect now it logged in but not rendering the page

```
def login_handle(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('your_name')
        password = request.POST.get('your_pass')
        # username = email
        # print(f"{username} and pasword is {password}")
        user = authenticate(request,username=username,password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Babe try again you are not authenticated")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("babe only post method applicable")
```

I am getting the error

[image]

Here is my app name home urls.py

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from home import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index,name="index"),

    # create agent
    path('create_agent_page',views.create_agent_page,name="create_agent_page"),
    path('create_agent',views.create_agent,name="create_agent"),


    path('signup_page',views.signup_page,name="signup_page"),
    path('login_page',views.login_page,name="login_page"),
    path('signup_handle',views.signup_handle,name="signup_handle"),
    path('login_handle',views.login_handle,name="login_handle"),

    #Lead handleing  

    path('create_lead',views.create_lead_page,name="create_lead"),
    path('follow_up/<int:id>',views.follow_up,name="follow_up"),
    path('update_lead/<int:id>',views.update_lead,name="update_lead"),
    # path('update_lead',views.update_lead,name="update_lead"),
    path('creat_handle_lead',views.creat_handle_lead,name="creat_handle_lead"),
    path('lead_list',views.lead_list,name="lead_list"),

]
```

here is my project urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls.conf import include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('leads/', include('home.urls')),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return redirect('')
```

This is wrong. You must do

```
from django.urls import reverse
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('app_name:url_pattern_name'))
```

or you can specify your url pattern manually

```
from django.urls import reverse
return HttpResponseRedirect('/dashboard/')
```

Comment: Well sir i am actually giving him a path my path is blank

Comment: SIr i have tried what you says now its a different error

Comment: Share your entire traceback, urls.py and template

Comment: ok sir just wait 1 minute

Comment: Done the edit have a look